# xaml c# chart with custom axis label

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, charts

I use `System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting` to draw and show a chart with a LineSeries whose Y values are in a range between 1 to 5. I add values to LineSeries with `System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair(TKey,TValue)`. Instead of showing numbers from 1 to 5 in the Y label chart, I want to show letters from E to A.

How can I achieve this results?

Comment: I use .NET Framework 4.5

Comment: I can't find information on that namespace. Could you be using System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First** create a Converter to convert the numeric values to alphabet ones:

```
 public class NumericToAlphaConverter:IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        switch (value.ToString())
        {
            case "1":
                return "A";
            case "2":
                return "B";
            case "3":
                return "C";
            case "4":
                return "D";
            case "5":
                return "E";
            default: return null;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**use** that converter to define a custom Y label style :

```
 <Style TargetType="chartingToolkit:AxisLabel">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="chartingToolkit:AxisLabel">
                                    <TextBlock DataContext="{TemplateBinding FormattedContent}" Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource NumericToAlphaConverter}}" />
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
```

here the hole UI and the corresponding code behind

```
<Window.Resources>
    <wpfApplication12:NumericToAlphaConverter x:Key="NumericToAlphaConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <chartingToolkit:Chart   Title="Line Series"  
    VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0" Height="254" >
        <chartingToolkit:LineSeries  x:Name="serie"
                                   IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Key}"
                                   DependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Value}"      
    IsSelectionEnabled="True"/>
        <chartingToolkit:Chart.Axes>
            <chartingToolkit:LinearAxis Orientation="Y" 
                                    Title="Y val" 
                                        Maximum="5"
                                        Minimum="1"
                                        >
                <chartingToolkit:LinearAxis.AxisLabelStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="chartingToolkit:AxisLabel">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="chartingToolkit:AxisLabel">
                                    <TextBlock DataContext="{TemplateBinding FormattedContent}" Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource NumericToAlphaConverter}}" />
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </chartingToolkit:LinearAxis.AxisLabelStyle>
            </chartingToolkit:LinearAxis>
        </chartingToolkit:Chart.Axes>

    </chartingToolkit:Chart>
</Grid>
```

the code behind :

```
public ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<int, int>> LineSeriesData = new ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<int, int>>()
    {
        new KeyValuePair<int, int>(12,1),
        new KeyValuePair<int, int>(5,2),
        new KeyValuePair<int, int>(5,3),
        new KeyValuePair<int, int>(5,4)

    };
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        serie.ItemsSource = LineSeriesData;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer, it works perfectly! But now I've another question for you: for my purposes, I cannot set LinearAxis in xaml code because I need to create a new LinearAxis everytime I want to show the graph (because maxValue of Y axis change). Is it possible to use Y label style defined in xaml code when I create a new LinearAxis in my C# code? If yes, how? Thanks in advance!

Comment: well, you don't need to recreate the Y linear axes by code each time, just define a property that will hold the max Y value and bind the Y maximum to it Maximum="{Binding MaxY}", and extend the converter to handle more that 5 letters(you could find a more cleaver way to do it instead of that ugly switch)

Comment: Thank you very much, now it works perfectly for my purposes! You've solved all my problems! :)